# Optimize rendering multiple components in React

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm using React Native for an Android TV app. I have a `Player` component that renders `Asset` components based on a JSON array. The Player component has a `setTimeout(() => {}, 1000)` that runs each second and sets the state value of `currentAsset` each second. In my current render function, I am rendering the assets individually:

```
render() {
    return (
        <><Asset asset={this.state.currentAsset} /></>
    );
}
```

My JSON object contains an array of asset data so the `setTimeout` is only looping through that array and setting `this.setState({currentAsset: jsonArray[currentLoopIndex])` which results in many renders of `Asset`. I have noticed a couple of errors recently. The first is `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` and the latter `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. Both have occurred after the app has run for an extended length of time. The `Asset` component simply renders a saved `image` or `video`. How can I optimize the code so that I am not re-rendering a new component each time state is changed? It seems like it would be more performant to re-render an already initialized component for an asset that has previously been rendered but I am unsure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

To not render each time the state is changed, you could try using createRef();
For example:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
}
```

The advantage of using a ref is that the component will not rerender each time the ref is updated. However, use these sparingly as it makes components less reusable.

For more information, check out the official docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).